# Why computing $n$-point correlations?

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, statistical-physics

I am trying to find a sufficiently convincing answer to this question, but it has been taking so much of my time and I can't get anywhere. It also follows my [previous question on PSE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/799732/thermal-ground-state/799781#799781).

In axiomatic QFT, one defines a quantum field theory as a theory that satisfies Wightman's axioms. The famous reconstruction theorem states that the theory can be recovered from the Wightman functions. All of this has imaginary time counterparts; the Osterwalder–Schrader axioms are used to define a Euclidean QFT, and the analytic continuation of the Wightman functions is the so-called Schwinger functions. Schwinger functions are correlations of the underlying Euclidean field, and from the mathematical point of view, one is interested in constructing these Schwinger functions, usually trying to use functional integrals, renormalization group techniques, etc.

Now, suppose I am *not* interested in QFT (in the sense that I don't want to quantize a classical field) but, instead, I want to study *many body quantum mechanics*. Then, one goes back to the scenario described in my previous linked question. For completeness, I will recall the definitions here.

Consider a system of $N$ fermions in a periodic box $\Lambda \subset \mathbb{R}^{d}$, described by the Hamiltonian
$$H_{N} = \sum_{k=1}^N(-\Delta_{x_k}-\mu) + \lambda \sum_{i< j} V(x_i-x_{j}) \tag{1}\label{1}$$
where $\lambda$ is some coupling constant, $\mu \in \mathbb{R}$ is the chemical potential and $V$ is a sufficiently well-behaved interaction function. After second quantization, we consider the fermionic Fock space described by a second quantized Hamiltonian $H$.

For simplicity, I will only consider a fermionic theory here. Suppose we have a theory in finite temperature $\beta = 1/T > 0$. Let $\psi_x^\pm$ be creation and annihilation operators for fermions and, for $\beta \ge t_i$, $i=1,\ldots,n$, $t_i\neq t_{j}$ for $i \neq j$, define the $n$-point (imaginary time) thermal Schwinger function:
\begin{align}
& S_{\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_n, \beta}(x_1,t_1,\ldots,x_n,t_n) \\[8pt]
:= {} & (-1)^\pi \frac{\operatorname{Tr}(e^{-(\beta-t_{\pi(1)})H} \psi_{x_{\pi(1)}}^{\sigma_{\pi(1)}}e^{-(t_{\pi(1)}-t_{\pi(2)})H} \psi_{\pi(2)}^{\sigma_{\pi(2)}}\cdots \psi_{x_{\pi(n)}}^{\sigma_{\pi(n)}}e^{-t_{\pi(n)}H})}{\operatorname{Tr}e^{-\beta H}}. \tag{2}\label{2}
\end{align}
Here, $\sigma = \pm 1$, $\pi$ is a permutation of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ such that $t_{\pi(1)} > t_{\pi(2)} > \cdots > t_{\pi(n)}$ and $(-1)^{\pi}$ is the parity of $\pi$.

In the mathematical physics literature, especially in the renormalization group community, these Schwinger functions seem ubiquitous. This is my main problem: from the point of view of many-body quantum mechanics, I don't see what is the real motivation to study these Schwinger functions described by (\ref{2}) (or even their zero-temperature limit). My reasons are the following:

- The thermodynamic properties of the system are obtained from the partition function or from the free energy. These are "zero" point functions.
- The two-point Schwinger function (also called the Green function in the physics literature) is, indeed, very important. One can obtain the ground state of the full Hamiltonian and even the spectrum. One can also obtain other interesting physical quantities, such as the occupation number.

But **Nowhere** I looked mention higher order (i.e. $n \ge 2$) Schwinger (or Green, if you prefer) functions to be fundamentally relevant. In some physics textbooks I checked, I don't even think these are introduced in the first place.

Of course, you can argue that in perturbation theory, one expands the interaction part (via Dyson series, using Trotter or analogous technique) and, if the interaction $V$ is a polynomial in the creation and annihilation operators, one will get the two-point Green function from $n$-point functions. But *these $n$-point Green functions are taken with respect to the free theory, not the full interacting theory*, so it is not the same as studying (\ref{2}) because the latter takes averages with respect to the interacting theory.

However, even these functions are said to be of great interest in the community. In [Gallavotti and Benfatto's book](https://press.princeton.edu/books/paperback/9780691044460/renormalization-group), these Schwinger functions are the primary object of interest in Chapter 3 and they claim that the reason is because (in the $\beta \to \infty$ limit) these define the energy of the ground state. A similar claim is made [in this review](https://inspirehep.net/literature/566029). However, as discussed in my PSE question, only the two-point Schwinger functions are necessary to obtain the ground state energy and spectrum, and I still don't know the real importance of higher order functions. I am sure there is a reason behind this interest, I just cannot find it explicitly stated.

Once again, I understand that the Schwinger functions are important in the context of axiomatic QFT. But I am taking a different route here: I want to motivate myself that these functions arise naturally in the *many-body theory*, and their study is interesting not only for mathematical but also by physical reasons.

Could someone clarify the real importance of studying these functions, both in the setting of finite and zero temperature? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7):

Quite generally, three-point (and higher order) correlators are used to reveal the non-Gaussian (read: nonclassical) character of the fields, see for example [Experimental characterization of a quantum many-body system via higher-order correlations](https://www.nature.com/articles/nature22310) (also on [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.03126)).

One topic where correlation functions of high order are routinely studied is quantum transport: if you measure the conductance (determined by the average current) you are measuring a one-point correlator, the shot noise of the current gives you a two-point correlator, and by measuring higher order correlators you can reconstruct the full probability distribution of the transferred charge, with useful information on the quantum statistics of the quasiparticles that carry the charge.

Comment: As far as I remember, the BCS model for superconductivity relies heavily on the four-point correlation function because of the effective interaction between Cooper pairs. Likewise for Bogolyubov's model for superfluidity.

Answer (score 5):

> Now, suppose I am not interested in QFT (in the sense that I don't want to quantize a classical field) but, instead, I want to study many body quantum mechanics.

Tough luck! :-) These are mathematically equivalent problems. Presuming that you are talking about non-relativistic many-body theory, the (probably fermionic) classical field in question would be obeying a Schrödinger equation with some possibly non-local interaction. If electromagnetic interactions are involved, then a quantized electromagnetic field has to be added to that. This is discussed in any introduction to many-body physics (e.g., Sec.1.2 of Mahan's *Many-particle physics* (1990)).

About triple and higher order correlations. Quantum mechanics is in a sense a generalization of statistical mechanics. In statistical mechanics a field $\Psi(x)$ is a "position dependent" random variable and $n$-point functions are expectation values $\mathbb{E}[\Psi(x_1) \cdots \Psi(x_n)]$. Without going into the details of any physical scenario, it is no great mystery that you might be at some point interested in triple or higher $n\ge 3$ field correlations. Even if you don't have a specific need for them, someone else might, and a complete statistical mechanical theory of the field $\Psi(x)$ should be able to provide you with them. In the case of quantum mechanics, statistical expectation values are replaced by quantum expectation values $\langle\Omega| \Psi(x_1) \cdots \Psi(x_n) |\Omega\rangle$ for some pure state $|\Omega\rangle$ (or an analogous expression with the density matrix of a mixed state). If the state is a stationary ground state (or a thermal equilibrium mixed state), such expectation values can be obtained from Wick rotating the corresponding Euclidean $n$-point functions.

One more point about perturbation theory. You have rightly pointed out in the question that $n$-point functions (of a free theory) for arbitrarily high $n$ are used to perturbatively build interacting theories. Suppose for a moment that you want to perturb an already interacting theory (changing one of the coupling constants, for instance). Then all the same formulas with $n$-point functions will work in the perturbative calculations, but the $n$-point functions will now be with respect to the base interacting theory.

Comment: Igor, thanks for your answer. I like your comments because this is what made me think about these questions in the first case. In fact, I was trying to use the analogy with statistical mechanics, where one wants to compute expectation of fields (which are pretty natural objects to study, of course). However, I came to the conclusion that the natural extension to quantum mechanics would be either expectation of time-independent creation and annihilation operators (if one is not interested in time evolution) or expectations of time dependent operators but *evaluated at the same time*. (cont)

Comment: Schwinger functions are evaluated at different times, and this is what makes the whole difference in my opinion. In other words, you cannot simply motivate these functions by arguing that one wants to compute averages, because the fields are taken at different times. And this led me to this question. If one is interested in Schwinger functions in the first place, one must have some physical reason other than "computing averages".

Comment: I only have one comment. If you can think of a way to compute spatially separated correlations, you can think of similar reasons to compute temporally separated correlations.

Answer (score 4):

In physics, you certainly want to do more than just find the energy eigenvalues that you get from the 2-point functions. You also want to evaluate matrix elements of operators in the corresponding eigenstates. Every such operator insertion implies another "point". For example, hadron structure studies in Lattice QCD are based on 3-point functions, all day long, every day of the year, as long as the computer runs.

Answer (score 2):

The $n$-point functions for $n\ge 3$ are required if you are interested in how your system responds to an external probe $\phi$ (e.g. an electromagnetic field). You have to couple this to your system via some term $\phi j(\psi)$ in the Hamiltonian $H$, where $j(\psi)$ is some polynomial in $\psi$, and then the derivative of the Green function (and hence the energies of the states) w.r.t. the external field will bring down additional terms $j(\psi)$, leading to higher-order $n$-point functions.